# Why does Vagrant resume do a provision

Tags: vagrant

Just upgraded my vagrant host to the latest v1.8.1 on OS X. Now when i do a suspend and resume, It performs a reprovisioning of the box.

The only fix i have found is to run this instead "vagrant up --no-provision".

I see a ticket open in the vagrant repo with other people experiencing the same problems. https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/6787

Surely this is not normal behavior, anyone else find a more permanent fix?

Comment: Nope - you've found the best path forward currently. I've noticed the 1.8.x branch has a number of issues, so unless you really need something from it I would consider just going back to 1.7.x until they are ironed out.

Comment: ok, thanks, at least now i know its not me.